# Django - extract image from pdf during saving process of an object

Tags: python, django

I am working on private portfolio, where I have model called 'Certification'.

```
class Certification(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    organiser = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_completed = models.DateField()
    pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to='static/media', blank=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images', blank=True)
```

I want to extract 'cover_image' from first page of the 'pdf_file' during creation of an object Certificate, the image will be used as a cover image of a tile in my front-end. I tried to use pdf2image library, but without a success - the function I wrote cannot handle file which is not saved yet. What script should I use to achieve this goal and where should it be placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long while I've came up to an idea how to manage this - all you had to do is write a receiver function [receiver function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#receiver-functions) and pass the newly created cover to the specific instance of an object

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Certification)
def extract_cover(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
if created:
    pdf = instance.file
    cover = convert_from_path(str(pdf), 100)
    cover = cover[0]
    cover_name = str(pdf)[12:-4]
    cover.save(cover_name + ".jpg", 'JPEG')

    instance.cover_image = cover_name + ".jpg"
    instance.save()
```